# Where IN clausula In LINQ con stringComparison

Tags: c#

Quiero hacer una extensión basada en la cláusula In de SQL pero en linq C # enviando el parámetro stringComparison pero me gustaría validar el parámetro T source y el parámetro IEnumerable list si son de tipo String los dos ya que solo la quiera cuando sean tipo String, ya que con el try cath no aseguraria o no me daria cuenta cuando falle ya que lo pueden aplicar a cualquier tipo.

```
class User
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public object idobj { get; set; }
        public Guid secondId { get; set; }
    }

    private static string methodPrint()
    {
        var list = new ArrayList { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        var listString = new List<string>();
        var enumerable = new List<User>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var user = new User { id = i, name = "Jose "+i , secondId = Guid.NewGuid(), idobj = i};
            enumerable.Add(user);
            if (list.Contains(i))
            {
                listString.Add(user.name.ToLower());
            }
        }

        var print = string.Join(" \n",enumerable.Where(c => c.name.In(listString, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).Select(c => c.name).ToArray());

        return print;
    }

    public static bool In<T>(this T source, IEnumerable<T> list, StringComparison comparisonType)
    {
        bool resultValue = false;
        try
        {
            if (source == null || list == null) return false;
            resultValue = list.Any(c => c.ToString().Contains(source.ToString(),comparisonType));
        }
        catch { }

        return resultValue;
    }

    public static bool Contains(this string sourceString, string value, StringComparison comparisonType)
    {
        return sourceString != null ? sourceString.IndexOf(value, comparisonType) >= 0 : false;
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(methodPrint());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: recuerda que el foro es en español, deberias traducir la pregunta

Comment: si ya lo cambie

Comment: Además por favor el código debe ir como texto

Comment: No termino de entender cual es tu problema. Podrías [edit] tu pregunta, copiar el codigo como texto en lugar de como imagenes, y explicar un poco mas donde estas teniendo dificultades? Porque, a primera vista, entiendo que tu código funciona correctamente, es así?

Comment: si funciona correctamente pero no tengo manera de validar si el tipo source es de tipo string y tbm el IEnumerable<T> list  verificar tbm si es un IEnumerable de tipo String

Comment: En ese caso...por que usas genéricos? Definelo como `public static bool In(this string source,IEnumerable<string> list, StringComparison comparisonType)`

Comment: Ok hare la verificacion correspondiente gracias por el comentario lo unico seria validar si el source y el list veienen null @Pikoh

Comment: Eso justamente lo tiene que hacer tu funcion Jose

Comment: @gbianchi creo que asi quedaria la funcion con la verificacion

Comment: @JoseDavidMuñozCruz en lugar de editar tu pregunta con la solución, es mejor que añadas una respuesta con ella. Pasadas 48h podrás aceptar tu propia respuesta.

Comment: ese try catch sin nada no sirve... para que poner algo asi si no podes controlar errores? mejor que salte...

Comment: @Pikoh ok gracias, lo tomare en cuenta tu comentario

Answer (score 0):

podrías `where` en tu funcion para permitir que `T` sea solo string

```
public static bool In<T>(this T source, IEnumerable<T> list, StringComparison comparisonType) where T : string
{
...
}
```

Te dejo el link a la documentación donde lo explican con mayor detalle https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters

Comment: Esta respuesta esta equivocada. No puedes usar `string`como restriccion, esta debe ser segun la documentación una interfaz, clase no sellada o parámetro de tipo. Mas información [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13344568/579895)

Comment: @Pikoh tiene razon me arroja el error `'string' is not a valid constraint. A type used as a constraint must be an interface, a non-sealed class or a type parameter.`